# ubuntu start stop working properly problem-ubuntu-desktop

Tags: kernel

Whenever I switch off or on my Ubuntu system on my whole screen " @ " got printed and in between many time i got black circle icon on my screen after pressing any key it got remove from the screen. Please help me out of this.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What video card and driver? What kernel? Please edit the question and add the info. Please do not use comments for question info.